# Why don't I see events relating to failed Kubernetes probes?

Tags: events, kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I have defined readiness and liveness probes for the container in a Kubernetes deployment. When these fail I expect to see their output included in an event for the pod. However I don't see such events. I do see other events for the same pod.

I am running on GKE, with Kubernetes v1.6.4.

The code that should produce the events is here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.6.4/pkg/kubelet/prober/prober.go#L94.

What I see instead is logs indicating that a "ref" for the container could not be retrieved. I see similar logs for other places in the code that try to record container-related events.

Is this a bug? These events are potentially very useful. In particular it's the only way to see output from a failing probe so that I can diagnose probes that are failing unexpectedly.

[I'm not certain if this is an appropriate issue for StackOverflow. Please let me know if it would be better raised as an issue in Github.]

Comment: I also have a GKE 1.6.4 cluster.
I followed [this example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-a-liveness-command) from the Kubernetes docs, and after about 40 seconds, I did see an even when the pod was killed for failing its liveness probe.  It looked like: 
```"liveness-exec_kube-system(4339b96a-5b7e-11e7-956e-42010a8a0fdc)" container "liveness" is unhealthy, it will be killed and re-created.
```

Comment: If you are able to, you could SSH to the node that the pod is running on, and check if the `!hasRef` condition is being hit.  You'd grep the kubelet logs for "No ref for container".

Comment: @EricTune Thank you. I have checked that it is indeed the "no ref for container" problem.

Comment: Filed an issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/49063

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that has been fixed in Kubernetes 1.6.7.